# : ошибка: incompatible type for argument 1

Tags: c, qt, qtcreator

столкнулся с такой ошибкой, на 85 строке:

```
/home/comp/Qt_project/untitled46/main.c:85: ошибка: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘processFrame’
             processFrame(frame1);
                          ^~~~~~
```

Вот код :

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

#include <linux/can.h>
#include <linux/can/bcm.h>


void processFrame(struct canfd_frame frame) {
  int len = 0;
  unsigned char data[8];

  printf("CAN ID : %d \n", frame.can_id);
  printf("frame.can_id : %03X \n", frame.can_id );
  // printf("LEN : %d \n", frame.can_dlc); len = frame.can_dlc;
  printf("LEN : %d \n", frame.len); len = frame.len;
  printf("len = %d \n", len);
  printf("DATA : ");
  for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
      printf(" [%u] ", frame.data[i]);
  printf("\n");
  for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
      data[i] = frame.data[i];
  printf("data : ");
  for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
      printf(" [%u] ", data[i]);
  printf("\n ---------------- \n");
}

/* omitted vital #includes and error checking */

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct ifreq ifr;
    struct sockaddr_can addr;
    struct can_frame frame;
    struct can_frame frame1;

    int s;

    memset(&ifr, 0x0, sizeof(ifr));
    memset(&addr, 0x0, sizeof(addr));
    memset(&frame, 0x0, sizeof(frame));
    memset(&frame1, 0x0, sizeof(frame));


    /* open CAN_RAW socket */
    s = socket(PF_CAN, SOCK_RAW, CAN_RAW);

    /* convert interface sting "can0" into interface index */
    strcpy(ifr.ifr_name, "can0");
    ioctl(s, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr);

    /* setup address for bind */
    addr.can_ifindex = ifr.ifr_ifindex;
    addr.can_family = PF_CAN;

    /* bind socket to the can0 interface */
    bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));

    while(1){
        /* first fill, then send the CAN frame */
        frame.can_id = 0x23;
        strcpy((char *)frame.data, "hello");
        frame.can_dlc = 5;
        write(s, &frame, sizeof(frame));

        /* first fill, then send the CAN frame */
        frame.can_id = 0x23;
        strcpy((char *)frame.data, "iCC2012");
        frame.can_dlc = 7;
        write(s, &frame, sizeof(frame));

        int numBytes =  read(s, &frame1, CAN_MTU);
        switch (numBytes)
        {
        case CAN_MTU:
            processFrame(frame1);
            break;
        case CANFD_MTU:
            // TODO: Should make an example for CAN FD создай функцию для считывания КАН ФД сообщений
            break;
        case -1:
            // Check the signal value on interrupt проверяем значение сигнала и прерывание
            if (EINTR == errno)
                break;
            // Delay before continuing маленькое тороможение
            perror("not read");
            usleep(100);
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    close(s);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Обычная опечатка.

Comment: @AnT такой тип ошибки я здесь не видел, он относиться к QtCreator-y и так ка я с ним работаю то не считаю что стоит обойти вниманием эту ошибку. Я заранее смотрел есть ли тут вопрос  по типу : **QtСreator выдал мне `ошибка: incompatible type `** И не одного вопроса он не предоставил, посему я и решил "заполнить " сию брешь . Ибо если не я сегодня, то завтра кто то другой _возможно вы :3_

Comment: Ошибка не имеет никакого отношения к QtCreator вообще. Это обычная *мгновенно узнаваемая* ошибка компилятора GCC, используемого QtCreator, упоминанием которой по "error: incompatible type for argument" весь интернет завален под завязку. Вы предлагаете устраивать вопросы-ответы на все виды опечаток со всеми комбинациями посторонних ключевых слов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Перевод ошибки : несовместимый тип аргумента.**

ошибка заключаться в использовании разных структур(*которые внешне сильно похожи* ): `canfd_frame` и `can_frame`

Надо пользоваться какой то одной структурой (я воспользовался структурой`can_frame` ), из за этого изменил только функцию `processFrame`, вот код:

```
void processFrame(struct can_frame frame) {
    int len = 0;
    unsigned char data[8];

    printf("CAN ID : %d \n", frame.can_id);
    printf("frame.can_id : %03X \n", frame.can_id );
    printf("LEN : %d \n", frame.can_dlc); len = frame.can_dlc;
//    printf("LEN : %d \n", frame->len); len = frame->len;
    printf("len = %d \n", len);
    printf("DATA : ");
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
        printf(" [%u] ", frame.data[i]);
    printf("\n");
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
        data[i] = frame.data[i];
    printf("data : ");
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
        printf(" [%u] ", data[i]);
    printf("\n ---------------- \n");
}
```

Также замечу что в функцию можно передать структуру как ввиде переменной `void processFrame(struct can_frame frame)` так и по ссылке `void processFrame(struct can_frame *frame)`    вот код :

```
   void processFrame(struct can_frame *frame) {
    int len = 0;
    unsigned char data[8];

    printf("CAN ID : %d \n", frame->can_id);
    printf("frame.can_id : %03X \n", frame->can_id );
    printf("LEN : %d \n", frame->can_dlc); len = frame->can_dlc;
//    printf("LEN : %d \n", frame->len); len = frame->len;
    printf("len = %d \n", len);
    printf("DATA : ");
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
        printf(" [%u] ", frame->data[i]);
    printf("\n");
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
        data[i] = frame->data[i];
    printf("data : ");
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
        printf(" [%u] ", data[i]);
    printf("\n ---------------- \n");
}
```

Comment: Ошибка заключается не только в использовании разных структур, а еще и в том, что параметр объявлен как указатель на структуру, а передается сама структура. То есть написана просто ерунда уровня "опечатка". В чем смысл таких вопросов? Вы не в состоянии без помощи интернета найти банальные опечатки в коде?

Comment: @AnT исправил . Также можете дополнить либо подкорректировать (большее теории и т.д. )ибо я не очень хорош в  программировании